# removing delay in sending string through tcp/ip

Tags: java, android, sockets, tcp

My project has a light switch which has an IP address and port and accepts strings to control. I am trying to create an application to switch this on and off.
My code works, however after the first click, there is a significant delay between the next click and the switch actually switching.

I have a button for on and off. main.java:

```
package com.android.lswitch;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Button;

public class lightswitch extends Activity {
/** Called when the activity is first created. */

@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.main);

    // Handle swon button
    Button swon = (Button) findViewById(R.id.swon);
    swon.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        public void onClick(View v) {
            sw(true);
        }
    });

    // Handle swoff button
    Button swoff = (Button) findViewById(R.id.swoff);
    swoff.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        public void onClick(View v) {
            sw(false);
        }
    });


}

private void sw(boolean swstate) {
    if (swstate == true) {
        Thread swonThread = new Thread(new swon());
        swonThread.start();    
    }

    if (swstate == false) {
    Thread swoffThread = new Thread(new swoff());
    swoffThread.start();    
    }

}
}
```

and button on java:
    package com.android.lswitch;

```
import java.io.BufferedWriter;
import java.io.OutputStreamWriter;
import java.io.PrintWriter;
import java.net.InetAddress;
import java.net.Socket;

public class swon implements Runnable {
public static final String SERVERIP = "10.0.0.25";
public static final int SERVERPORT = 4000;


public void run(){
try {
    InetAddress serverAddr = InetAddress.getByName(SERVERIP);

    Socket socket = new Socket(serverAddr, SERVERPORT);

    String swon = "A55A6B0550000000FFFBDE0030C8";
    String but0 = "A55A6B0500000000FFFBDE002066";

    PrintWriter out = new PrintWriter( new BufferedWriter
            ( new OutputStreamWriter(socket.getOutputStream())),true);

    out.println(swon);
    out.println(but0);
    socket.close();
} catch(Exception e) {
}
    finally {

    }
}
}
```

button off is virtually the same but with different strings.
I'm new to android coding (and java coding) so can't see where the hold up is. Do I need to flush the strings somewhere? or is there a better way of tackling this project?

Cheers

Comment: Do you experience this delay also when using a different client than android? The problem could be on the server side

Comment: Hi, no. I have a windows application where there is zero delay. Cheers

Answer (score 1):

`PrintWriter` may be buffered, so you should definitely `flush()` it before issuing any `close()` operation on the underlying socket.

It is also preferable to call `PrintWriter.close()` instead of `Socket.close()`, e.g., in a `finally` block, such as:

```
PrintWriter out = new PrintWriter( new BufferedWriter
        ( new OutputStreamWriter(socket.getOutputStream())),true);

try {
  out.println(swon);
  out.println(but0);
  out.flush();
} finally {
  out.close();
}
```

Comment: The printer writer is set to auto flush mode (in constructor), so each println will automatically flush the buffer

Comment: Cheers, I tried putting the out.close(); (and socket.close(); ) in the finally block, but I get the error 'out cannot be resolved)

Comment: @Chris: You probably put it into your original finally block. Try resembling the structure I posted. Apart from that you do not need to call socket.close() - out.close() will do that for you. If it still does not work out, please post your updated source code.

Comment: Hi, I try the following code, but get an error in eclipse saying 'out cannot be resolved'

    try {
    InetAddress serverAddr = InetAddress.getByName(SERVERIP);
 Socket socket = new Socket(serverAddr, SERVERPORT);
    
        String swon = "A55A6B0550000000FFFBDE0030C8";
        String but0 = "A55A6B0500000000FFFBDE002066";
                     
 PrintWriter out = new PrintWriter( new BufferedWriter( new     OutputStreamWriter(socket.getOutputStream())),true);

        out.println(swon);
        out.println(but0);
 //socket.close();
 } catch(Exception e) {
 }
 finally {
 out.close();}
    }

Comment: @tg: Sorry, I can't get the code showing correctly in the comment